# How to append to path url after replacing portion in url path using Python

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, url, urllib

I'm new to urllib so I apologize if this seems beginner. I've tried to search the documentation on this but haven't found anything yet. I'm looking to change the path of a url using urllib but still append more url path after my change or replacement.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
url = 'https://www.espn.com/nhl/team/schedule/_/name/vgs/seasontype/2'
parsed = urlparse(url)
print(parsed)
```

Here is the code so far and this gives me output of:

```
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='www.espn.com', path='/nhl/team/schedule/_/name/vgs/seasontype/2', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

I'm looking to change the abbv portion in this path:`/name/abbv/seasontype/2`. The `seasontype/2` will remain the same for this data I'm trying to grab however the team name abbreviation will be changing. Is it possible to cycle through a list of team abbreviations and still append `seasontype/2` after the new team name?

Comment: so if you simply want to replace the abbrev 'vgs' with a different team abbreviation (1) set up a list of team abbreviations for the teams of interest. (2) set up a request_string of the form ```url =f'https://www.espn.com/nhl/team/schedule/_/name/{team_abrev}/seasontype/2'```,  (3) in a for loop of the form ```for team_abrev in team_abbreviations:``` execute the ```parsed = urlparse(url)```

Comment: @itprorh66 Would you set that for loop up at the beginning of the block? so before you declare your url? and would you set your url inside of the for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
team_abbreviations = ['vgs', 'mtl', 'cgy']
for tm_abrv in team_abbreviations:
    url = f'https://www.espn.com/nhl/team/schedule/_/name/{tm_abrv}/seasontype/2'  
    parsed = urlparse(url)
    print(parsed)
```

Comment: Please run your code to make sure it works before posting it as an answer.

Comment: Also, while code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Comment: @PranavHosangadi if you read the previous comments, I already explained what I was doing before I provided the answer.  The answer was to provide the OP with a more extensive code solution.  With regard to testing before I provide an answer, I normally do, but since I have no idea what the OP is trying to accomplish other than insert the team abbreviation into the url call, I have no way of testing.

Comment: 1. Comments are temporary and are meant to clarify the question, not to add an answer. If you posted comments that answer the question, you should include those comments in your answer when you post an answer so that it's self-contained. 2. "I have no idea what OP wants": Then ask them to clarify instead of posting a potentially wrong answer. Regardless, the code you posted _wasn't even syntactically sound_ (missing quotes, undefined names), and I wanted to bring that to your attention.